# Using Pandas to transfer data from CSV format to JSON with large amount of fieldnames

Tags: python, json, pandas

Trying to take a file that looks like this

[image: data]

and turn it into Json with the below code. It isn't printing the values properly. The values aside from the top columns are print as NULL.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import json


df = pd.read_csv('1mins data.csv', 'r', ",")
df.head()
fieldnames = df.columns[1:-1]
print(fieldnames[:])

jsonfile = open('1mins data.json', 'w')
fieldnames=fieldnames
reader = csv.DictReader( df, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

After taking the advice given below I've updated the script.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import json


df = pd.read_csv('1mins data.csv', 'r', ",")
df.head()

df.columns[1:-1].to_json(path_or_buf='1minsdata.json')
```

Now i received this error,

```
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_json'
```

Fixed it by doing this

```
    import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import json


df = pd.read_csv('1mins data.csv', 'r', ",")
df.set_index('Time')df.to_json()

df.to_json(path_or_buf='1mins data.json')
df.to_json()
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There is one method of pandas to convert data frame to json check link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it can solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn a pandas DataFrame into a json string with

```
df.to_json()
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: This isn't working as it's giving me this error included in notes above